# Table MySQL Data in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I'm writing some code that returns the results of an event. In this table I have some fields that are populated with data from MySQL, including a download link for a certificate.

But now, I need to add a search field. This is what I have done so far:

```
<?php     
include "open.php";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM results";

if (isset($_POST['search'])){

    $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_box']);

    $sql .= "WHERE Name = '{$search_term}' ";
    $sql .= "OR Place = '{$search_term}'";
}

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());        
?>

<form name="search_form" method="POST" action="teste3.php">        
    Search: <input type="text" name="search_box" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search">
</form>

<table width="70%" cellpadding="5" cellspace="5">        
    <tr>            
        <td>
            <strong>Place</strong>
        </td>
        <td>
            <strong>Name</strong>
        </td>
        <td>
            <strong>Category</strong>
        </td>
        <td>
            <strong>Certificate</strong>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){ ?>
    <tr>                        
        <td><?php echo $row['Place']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Category']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <a href="http://(...)/<?php echo $row['Place']; ?>.pdf"
             style="color: #000000" target="blank">Download Certificate</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>                
</table>
```

But for some reason when I do a test search, the browser echoes:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '= 'ulisses' OR Place = 'ulisses'' at line 1.

Comment: You're missing a space between `resultados` and `WHERE` when you concatenate them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide some space as

```
$sql .= " WHERE Nome = '{$search_term}' ";
$sql .= "OR Lugar = '{$search_term}'";
```

The way you have done your query will become as

```
SELECT * FROM resultadosWHERE Nome = 'some val' OR Lugar = 'some val'
```

Comment: Thanks. When i search from numbers it works, but i think i need something else to search for names. Already tried '%{$search_term}%', but don't think its enough. Do you know why its not working?

Comment: if you search for string it should work something as where col = 'val' and if you provide the where col LIKE '%val%' it will find the matching pattern :-)

Comment: I knew i had forgot something! Thanks! :D

Comment: One more thing, if i want to order by column, how can it be done? I'm trying hard but i'm not having luck.

Comment: you can do as select * from table where col1 = 'someval' OR col2 = 'someval' ORDER BY col1 ... You can add multiple ORDER BY as ORDER BY col1,col2

Comment: Already done that. I did not say properly. I have the columns, and when i click them, i want it to order ASC/DESC, but i think i need to change completly the code for that purpose.